# What are the pros and cons of using swap file on Ubuntu 16.04? Is it recommended to use swap file over swap partition on current Ubuntu version?

Tags: swap

I am planning to implement swap file over swap partition on Ubuntu 16.04. Going through various blogs I found that hibernation is only supported by swap partition and resizing is privileged on swap file. 
Are there any significant reasons for not using swap file in Linux systems?

Comment: there's no difference between swap file and swap partition nowadays. But you should avoid them and use zram instead https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/499485/44425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original kernel (4.13) of 17.10 and later solved the slow swap file issue. Performance was the sole reason to change. Before then, a swap partition was superior.

Which kernel do you use? Find it with `cat /proc/version` then click [edit] and add that useful information. If < 4.13, stay with a swap partition.

If your motivation is enabling hibernation, see this [article on alternative methods](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate).