# Readyboost on linux

Tags: manjaro

I wanted to know if you can do "readyboost" in Linux. ReadyBoost is a program that caches files that are frequently used by Windows 10. It stores the cached files on USB flash drive(s) or SD memory card. I use Manjaro i3. My laptop is an HP Stream with 2GB RAM and 32GB Hard Drive.

Comment: Is your 32GB hard drive really a spinning disk? Surely on an HP Stream it's an SSD?

Comment: Yes... 32gb ssd and 2gb solid

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in trying to use something like ReadyBoost because there is no spinning disk to speed up. (Your 32GB disk is already solid state.)

Comment: I get it. What is the alternative?

Comment: A larger storage card in your computer

Comment: The HP Stream does not let you change to expand the ram. I only have 2gb

Answer (score 0):

You can create a swap partition on your USB drive.  But  swapping to that is going to be WAY slower than swapping to the EMMC.  I recommend creating a swap partition on your 32GB EMMC.  4GB will do. Its typically recommended to use 2x your system ram. Don’t forget to add it to your fstab

Comment: no, a swap partition is much slower than zram. [Use zram instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499645/44425). The suggestion of 2x the system is outdated long ago

Comment: In their situation zram isn’t going to be verry useful.  They are limited to 2GB of memory and most things will want of that.  Chrome is out of the question on this thing. as it will start swapping things in and out dragging the machine to a crawl.

Comment: I know. But it's still better than swapping to the dreadfully slow eMMC (which is far slower than SSD)

Comment: It will cause more issues than it solves with such a pitiful amount of memory.    Sadly there is not much that can be done here.   Plus you wont get much improvement. (Perhaps another 25% usable ram) if you use half of your ram for it.   And that leaves you stuck 1gb of ram usable in a conventional way.