# Why swap still used?

Tags: swap

My system has 72GB of RAM.

My program ( build code ) uses about 7GB of RAM to build code.

I don't understand why swap (HDD RAM) is still used? Since there is about 65GB of free memory.

Comment: I gather this "65GB of free memory" is what is reported by `free -h` ? it's interesting you say your program uses 7GB, and you think that the other 65GB should be free ... is nothing else **at all** running?

Comment: Also [How do I use swap space for emergencies only?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/499485/100397)