# Auto detect RAM and create double the swap memory

Tags: linux, memory, dd, swap, ram

I'm able to auto detect RAM in GB as below and round off to the nearest integer:

```
printf "%.f\n" $(grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '$3=="kB"{$2=$2/1024^2;$3="GB";} 1' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Output:

```
4
```

I multiply by 2 to determine the required swap as 8GB

```
ans=`expr $(printf "%.f\n" $(grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | awk '$3=="kB"{$2=$2/1024^2;$3="GB";} 1' | awk '{print $2}')) \* 2`
echo "$ans"G
```

Output:

```
8G
```

With the below commands I try to create 8GB swap memory.

```
echo "Creating $ans GB swap memory"
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs="$ans"G count=1048576

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
sudo swapon --show
```

However, I get the below error:

```
Creating 8 GB swap memory
dd: memory exhausted by input buffer of size 8589934592 bytes (8.0 GiB)
mkswap: error: swap area needs to be at least 40 KiB
swapon: /swapfile: read swap header failed.
```

Can you please suggest and help me auto-create swap memory which Ideally should be double of that of the RAM.

System details:

```
root@DKERP:~# uname -a
Linux DKERP 5.4.0-124-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 02:23:37 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@DKERP:~# free -g -h -t
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.8Gi       1.0Gi       207Mi        54Mi       2.6Gi       2.5Gi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
Total:        3.8Gi       1.0Gi       207Mi
```

Comment: The advice to have 2x swap size was for 2 decades ago and was obsolete long ago, just don't do that and [use zram instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499645/44425)

Comment: swap size > RAM is still useful on systems that will be suspended to disk - e.g. laptops.  A machine can't suspend if there's nowhere to store the RAM contents, and Linux uses swap space for that.

Comment: Use `bs=1M` and set `count` to the number of megabytes you want the swapfile to be

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why your `dd` command didn't work is because you set dd's block size to 8 GB.  i.e. you told it to read and write 8 GiB at a time, which would require a RAM buffer of 8 GB.  As Marcus said, 8 GiB is more RAM than you have, so a buffer of that size isn't going to work.

And ~ 8 billion megabytes (8 GiB x 1M = 8 **peta**bytes, 9,007,199,254,740,992 bytes) is way more disk space than you have too....it's way more than most high-end storage clusters in the world would have.

It would work if you used reasonable values for both bs and count.  For example, 1 MiB x 8K = 8 GiB:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1048576 count=8192
```

or

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=8K
```

Comment: Surprised if this works. Quoting `swapon(8)`: "truncate(1) create files with holes. These files will be rejected by swapon." I normally use `fallocate` instead. However: "files created by fallocate(1) may be interpreted as files with holes too depending of the filesystem." Not sure what FSes that's referring to, but it's at least not a problem with ext4.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've use truncate for swap files (and for VM image files) in the past, and it worked.  On the rare occasion I need them, I use ZFS ZVOLs now.  Using `dd` with reasonable parameters definitely works, so I'll just edit out the truncate stuff.

Comment: @JoL It _is_ a problem for ext4, but it's mitigated if, for whatever reason, the filesystem is already on a loopback device (e.g. if you're using LVM or LUKS). The reason is that `swapon` will directly map the blocks as swap, completely bypassing the filesystem, so all the blocks must exist (this is what holes interferes with). If you're using a loopback device, then any access will necessarily not be "direct".

Answer (score 5):

You're explicitly instructing `dd` to read a block of twice the RAM size into RAM. That cannot succeed.

Instead, simply ... not do that.

Comment: Thus far, i have been manually creating swap by the same approach where I used to give `dd bs=<twice the memory as that of the RAM`. I roughly remember that swap can be 
 twice that of RAM. Can you suggest how can I get optimal swap memory created automatically? @Marcus-Müller

Comment: You are telling `dd` to read 1 billion blocks, where each block is 8 GB in size. That a) requires `dd` to have 8 GB of RAM available so that it can buffer at least one block, and b) will result in a swapfile of 8 petabytes, which means you need to have 8 petabytes of free disk space. As this answer says, just don't do that, and it will work.

Comment: @Ashar it is important to realize two things, the size of the file you will create is BS * COUNT.  The second is that even though /dev/zero is fictional, `dd` does not know that, and it will read at least a BS of it into memory.  keep BS at 1M and modify count to the number of gigs * 1024.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with `dd` and manually setting block sizes. They don't matter for correctness in most cases, at least not on Linux with regular files or block devices. Use something more user-friendly instead.

You usual Linux installations, you probably have the GNU coreutils versions of the standard tools. If so, you can just use e.g.

```
gigs=8
head -c "${gigs}G" /dev/zero > /swapfile
```

to create that 8-gig zero-filled file.

If you don't have the GNU tools, many versions of `head` support the `-c` option with a bare number, so e.g.

```
gigs=8
head -c $((gigs * 1024 * 1024 * 1024)) /dev/zero > /swapfile
```