# Two questions about Linux swap

Tags: swap

Which is better, a /swapfile or a dedicated partition? Disk space and installed memory are not an issue.

I currently have a dual-boot system with Windows 11 and Linux Mint Cinnamon 21.1, both in English. I am now adding two more Linux OSes: a French Linux Mint 21.1 and Kubuntu 22.04 in English.

With the installation of three Linux OS's, do I need a swap for each, or will the installation detect an existing file or partition?

Comment: If you have enough RAM and you don't need hibernation, you can do fine without SWAP.

Comment: [just enable zram and forget about swap partitions or swap files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499645/44425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're careful, there's no practical difference between a `swap` partition and a `swap` file, except:

- `swap` partitions are harder to resize than `swap` files.
- It's possible to create a non-contiguous (invalid) `swap` file. `swap` partitions are contiguous by specification.

Once you've created a `swap` partition, any Linux *should* be able to use it. Windows probably not.

For a `swap` file to be useable by multiple Linuxes, the `swap` file will have to reside on a filesystem that gets mounted early by each Linux. Synchronization between `mount` and `swapon` is hard.

Comment: Since you have lots of memory, SWAP is optional - I don't bother with one. However, if you have a laptop which hibernates, you will need to provide a swap option.

Comment: And if  you want to use hibernation you will not be able to share swap partitions

Comment: The three OS are Debian based. They are two different language copies of Linux Mint Cinnamon 21.1, and one English Kubuntu 22.04. They share a single 2TB data drive. 

My approach is overcautious because of my early use of Linux starting over a decade ago. Because of this, I consecutively installed  three Linux OS where each OS had a 2gb partition listed by UUID in fstab, I noticed later that the two added OS used the first installed swap partition instead of their own. Then, later I started to use a /swapfile in the first but did not declare it in the other fstab.